# WorldClim models for future bioclimatic variables

Tags: data-request, geospatial, climate, models

About a year ago I downloaded tiff files with bioclimatic variables from particular CMIP6 model projections through WorldClim:

https://www.worldclim.org/data/cmip6/cmip6_clim10m.html

Previously, I believe they had 23 GCMs with tiffs for projected bioclimatic variables available for download, but now only have 9.

Are the other files available anywhere else? I know they have the GCMs from CMIP5 on their website but they do not use the same SSPs or timeslices.